# How early can you go through security in Gatwick if you've already checked in?

Tags: security, prioritypass

I am looking at booking a flight with a 15 hour layover in London, but it means flying into Stansted and self-transferring to Gatwick. This isn't a problem, but I am thinking it will be nice to stay overnight at an airport hotel in Gatwick (like BLOC) , with my next flight departing at 9am. My question is, if I've got a boarding pass for the next day (via online check-in), will I be allowed through security the night before to grab a free dinner at a lounge? I have Priority Pass and would love to save a bit of money on food, plus the BLOC hotel is steps from the South Terminal Security. I just don't know if they'll let me in 12 hours before my morning flight...

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to stay the an airport hotel, why would you want to go through security? There aren't any airside hotels at Gatwick.

Comment: @Cory I’m not sure I’ve understood your question - you want to book a landside hotel, go through security to get a free dinner, exit security to go to your hotel, then go back through security to board your flight?

Comment: Assuming your priority pass allows you a free meal, [this page](https://www.prioritypass.com/en/lounges/united-kingdom/london-gatwick/lgw7-no1-gatwick) says about Lounge No. 1: *"Access is permitted 3 hours prior to scheduled flight departure."* It seems a strange question - why would they allow you to pop in and out and allow anyone with a future boarding pass to have *several* free meals?